# Azure Devops OData Descendants doesn't return any result

Tags: azure-devops, odata

I am trying to retrieve sum of "CompletedWork" from their child tasks for per Bug/PBI/Feature items through Odata.

Here is query;

```
{AzureDevopsURL}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?$filter=(WorkItemType eq 'Bug' or WorkItemType eq 'Epic' or WorkItemType eq 'Feature' or WorkItemType eq 'Product Backlog Item'  ) and (State ne 'Removed' )&$select=WorkItemId,WorkItemType,Effort&$expand=Descendants($apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'Task' and State ne 'Removed')/aggregate($count as CountOfTasks, CompletedWork with sum as TotalCompletedWork))&$orderby=CreatedDate desc&$top=500
```

Sample result;

```
{
     "Descendants": [],
     "Effort": 1.0,
     "WorkItemId": 9856,
     "WorkItemType": "Product Backlog Item"
}
```

Descendants doesn't return any value.
Can someone point me please what I am missing here ?